# Zurb Foundation template glitches in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, zurb-foundation

[This](http://postimg.org/image/tsmcd9el3/) is how it looks when I switch sections or tabs.

[This](http://postimg.org/image/6srotm37p/) is after a second.

What can I do about this? It only happens when I'm using firefox, I'm probably using older foundation version, but I can't really tell, because there is no version numbers in js or css files. I found that if I "data-options="deep_linking: true"" is not there, that doesn't happens, but to give links to sections, it's completely needed, so I don't know how to fix this.

```
<section style="padding-top: 53px;" class="session active">
  <h5 style="center: 0px;" class="title"><a href="#panel1">section1</a></h5>
    <div style="" class="content" data-slug="panel1">
    </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <h5 style="left: 165px;" class="title"><a href="#panel2">section2</a></h5>
    <div style="" class="content" data-slug="panel2">
    </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <h5 style="left: 165px;" class="title"><a href="#panel3">section3</a></h5>
  <div style="" class="content" data-slug="panel3">
    <?php include '' ?>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <h5 style="left: 165px;" class="title"><a href="#panel4">section4</a></h5>
  <div style="" class="content" data-slug="panel4">
    <?php include '' ?>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <h5 style="left: 165px;" class="title"><a href="#panel5">section5</a></h5>
  <div style="" class="content" data-slug="panel5">
    <?php '' ?>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <h5 style="left: 165px;" class="title"><a href="#panel6">section6</a></h5>
    <div style="" class="content" data-slug="panel6">
      <?php include '' ?>   
    </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to help you with your question, we need you to include code and if you can provide a small example that reproduces the issue, it will go a long way to getting a solution.  Sites like jsfiddle.net are a great resource for creating javascript, css, and HTML examples.

Comment: I need more reputation to post more than 2 links, so http://paste.ubuntu.com/6468756/

Comment: Here is that foundation.js file http://paste.ubuntu.com/6473291/ And here is CSS http://paste.ubuntu.com/6473299/

Comment: and here is zepto.js http://paste.ubuntu.com/6473330/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6473601/ here is my footer and header

Comment: normalize.css http://paste.ubuntu.com/6473607/

Comment: My suggestion to you is to create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net that uses the minimum amount of code to reproduce the issue.  Sometimes just going through this exercise will help you narrow down and find the problem on your own.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ronalds88/gMqF8/4/ here, nothing happens, as my example doesn't work, maybe somebody can edit that to match the head I posted back in the link  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6473601/  here is collaboration link http://jsfiddle.net/Ronalds88/gMqF8/4/#&togetherjs=52I3017yOb

Comment: Problem could be similar to this https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2857